# spring @Transactional JDBC Template MySQL DB not rolling back

Tags: spring-aop, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am trying to implement the Spring @transactional with jdbc templates from the service layer calling 
2 insert methods in a DAOImpl and using simplejdbctemplate to the insert and i see in the logs that spring creates a new transaction on my service method and my first insert suceeds and the second insert fails and even though it says it is rolling back on the same connection the first insert never get rolled back from my Mysql DB.(i am using innodb engine).

Here is my service method.

```
@Service
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager")
public class NewWizardService{
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dataSourcesConfig.xml");
    UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO)ctx.getBean("userDAO");
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Throwable.class,  readOnly=false)
    public void createNewFirm()
    {

    userDAO.insert1();
    userDAO.insert2();

    }
```

}

Here is my datasource and transaction manager spring configuration.

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${jdbc.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Here is my log trace.

```
2012-03-28 16:56:31,460 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [com.CAIS.wizardService.NewWizardServiceImpl.createNewFirm]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.RuntimeException
2012-03-28 16:56:31,654 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - Acquired Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@7d627b8b] for JDBC transaction
2012-03-28 16:56:31,660 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - Switching JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@7d627b8b] to manual commit
2012-03-28 16:56:31,663 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL update
2012-03-28 16:56:31,663 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into client (fullName, createDate, createUser) values (?, ?, ?)]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,663 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2012-03-28 16:56:31,664 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cais]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,816 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
2012-03-28 16:56:31,833 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - SQL update affected 1 rows
2012-03-28 16:56:31,840 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '01000', error code '1265', message [Data truncated for column 'createDate' at row 1]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,842 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL update
2012-03-28 16:56:31,842 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] - Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into client (fullName, createDate, createUser) values (?, ?, ?)]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,918 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Finished creating instance of bean 'Sybase'
2012-03-28 16:56:31,918 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,918 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] - Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@6cf84b0a]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,920 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] - Database product name cached for DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@6cf84b0a]: name is 'MySQL'
2012-03-28 16:56:31,920 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] - SQL error codes for 'MySQL' found
2012-03-28 16:56:31,920 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator] - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '1406', will now try the fallback translator
2012-03-28 16:56:31,920 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator] - Extracted SQL state class '22' from value '22001'
2012-03-28 16:56:31,921 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2012-03-28 16:56:31,923 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction rollback
2012-03-28 16:56:31,923 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@7d627b8b]
2012-03-28 16:56:31,934 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] - Releasing JDBC Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@7d627b8b] after transaction
2012-03-28 16:56:31,934 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use @Transactional instead of @TransactionConfiguration because it is for transactional tests.
@Transactional is fine for a single txManager, but if you have more than one, you can change your tx anno. like @Transactional("productTxManager") or @Transactional("orderTxManager").

Answer (score 0):

Your `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>` needs to be defined in your webapp-serlet.xml.

You will find an explaination here : [Spring @Transactional annotations ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538345/spring-transactional-annotations-ignored)